# Unity 3D is not loading new references from MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to create a new variable with:

`public Text customText;`

To use the type `Text`, I need to include:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

But this reference doesn't exist in my list of references on MonoDevelop.
I download it manually and added the reference manually; now I can use the `Text` type and import the `UnityEngine.UI`.

Well, here is the issue. When I compile my solution, on MonoDevelop I get this error:

`Error: The compiler appears to have crashed. Check the build output pad for details. (Assembly-CSharp)`.

But on Unity3D I get the error:

```
Assets/UI/Scripts/HudController.cs(2,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `UI' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

The dll `UnityEngine` is by default in the list of references, but not the `UnityEngine.UI`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you have to actually download the annoying ios or android systems for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced this problem. Actually i've seen few solutions, but they helped me for only few launches of Unity.
Here is the links:

1) http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unityengine-ui-dll-is-in-timestamps-but-is-not-known-in-assetdatabase.274492/#post-2015083 (post by j.robichaud)

2) http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/847994/unityeditorui-reference-missing.html

I hope any of it will help you.
In my case only reinstall was the cure. :)